# get data of rows that are not set as foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get data of rows from a table that are not set as foreign keys in the related table. 
Please guide me on this in Laravel. I have used this but it's returning all data

```
$pages = DB::table('client_requests')
                ->leftJoin('bid_requests', 'client_requests.id', '=', 'bid_requests.client_request_id')
                ->select('client_requests.*')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Why you doesn't want to add a relations in you model and use it?

Comment: Share your table structure with us ? (at least these 2 tables)

Comment: Thanks for your support issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for your support. The problem was solved. This is the solution. It will be helpful for anyone with same issue. To get rows of data that is not set as foreign key in related table this is the way to get it in laravel.

```
$pages = DB::table('client_requests')
                ->leftJoin('bid_requests', 'client_requests.id', '=', 'bid_requests.client_request_id')
                ->select('client_requests.*')
                ->where('bid_requests.client_request_id','=',null)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```